# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55

Tags: android

click a button to add Linear Layout within another layout

the on click listener is:

```
question_next.setOnClickListener {
            if(validate()){
                question = question_question.text.toString()
                marks = question_marks.text.toString()
                answer = questions_answer.text.toString()

                val questionModel = QuestionModel(question, marks,option_list,null,answer)
                question_list.add(questionModel)

                CreateAndAppendQuestionListLayout()       //62
                total_mark += marks.toInt()
                total_mark_view.text = "Total marks: "+total_mark.toString()
                question_question.text!!.clear()
                question_marks.text!!.clear()
                questions_answer.text!!.clear()
                option_question.removeAllViews()
                option_list.clear()
            }
        }


fun CreateAndAppendQuestionListLayout(){
        val finalQuestion = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.final_question)
        val layoutInfate = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        for(i in question_list.indices){
            val tempQuestion = layoutInfate.inflate(R.layout.question_,null)      //125
            val questionNumber = tempQuestion.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question_layout_number)
            val questionStatement = tempQuestion.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question_layout_question)
            val questionMark = tempQuestion.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question_layout_mark)
            val optionView = tempQuestion.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.question_layout_option)

            questionNumber.text = (i+1).toString()
            questionStatement.text = question_list[i].question.toString()
            questionMark.text = question_list[i].mark.toString()
            val optionList = question_list[i].option as MutableList
            for(j in optionList.indices){
                val tempOption = layoutInfate.inflate(R.layout.option_,null)
                val optionNumber = tempOption.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.option_no)
                val optionText = tempOption.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.option_text)

                optionNumber.text = (j+1).toString()
                optionText.text = optionList[j]

                optionView.addView(tempOption)
            }


            finalQuestion.addView(tempQuestion)
        }
    }
```

whenever i click the button my application is crashed.
Status of logcat is:

> 2021-05-24 10:39:40.671 6013-6013/com.example.sikyann
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.sikyann, PID: 6013
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55 in com.example.sikyann:layout/question_: Binary XML file line #55 in
> com.example.sikyann:layout/question_: Error inflating class 
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55 in com.example.sikyann:layout/question_: Error inflating class
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
> at com.example.sikyann.Activity.CreateQuestionPaperActivity.CreateAndAppendQuestionListLayout(CreateQuestionPaperActivity.kt:125)
> at com.example.sikyann.Activity.CreateQuestionPaperActivity$onCreate$2.onClick(CreateQuestionPaperActivity.kt:62)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7580)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7531)
> at android.view.View.access$3900(View.java:842)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28871)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8214)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a
> descendant).
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:221)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:196)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:131)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:110)
> at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:266)
> at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:247)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532) 
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 
> at com.example.sikyann.Activity.CreateQuestionPaperActivity.CreateAndAppendQuestionListLayout(CreateQuestionPaperActivity.kt:125) 
> at com.example.sikyann.Activity.CreateQuestionPaperActivity$onCreate$2.onClick(CreateQuestionPaperActivity.kt:62) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7580) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7531) 
> at android.view.View.access$3900(View.java:842) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28871) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8214) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).

You need to use a theme that is derived from Theme.AppCompat.  YOu probably shouldn't be passing in null for the parent view anyway.  You're adding it to finalQuestion eventually, just pass finalQuestion in as the parent.  That will make it use the theme from finalQuestion, and automatically add it for you.